# nginx authentication through mysql and libpam

Tags: mysql, nginx, authorization, pam

I have installed NGINX server. **The requirement is to allow only certain IP addresses to access this service**. The list of allowed IP are stored in a MYSQL database.

I was able to install and configure **libpam-mysql and nginx-extras** and was successfuly able to login to the services through username and password as defined in database.

Would request to please provide suggestions/pointers to move in correct direction.

Note1: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/ Talks about limiting the access to certain IP set. Can we somehow link this to MYSQL database?

Note2: Can the NGINX auth module somehow know the connecting device's IP address???